# Can't read variable that was stored from within a while loop, when out of the while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I can't for the life of me see why I can not read the postPrioity outside the while loop.
I tried "export postPrioity="500"" still didn't work.

Any ideas?

-- or in plan text --

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "/files.txt" | while read namesInFile; do   
            postPrioity="500"
            #This one shows the "$postPrioity" varible, as '500'
            echo "weeeeeeeeee ---> $postPrioity <--- 1"
done
            #This one comes up with "" as the $postPrioity varible. GRRR
            echo "weeeeeeeeee ---> $postPrioity <--- 2"
```

OUTPUT: (I only have 3 file names in files.txt)

```
weeeeeeeeee ---> 500 <--- 1
weeeeeeeeee ---> 500 <--- 1
weeeeeeeeee ---> 500 <--- 1
weeeeeeeeee --->  <--- 2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pipe operator creates a subshell, see [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_line.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done) and [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). Solution: Don't use `cat`, it's useless anyway.

```
#!/bin/bash
postPriority=0
while read namesInFile
do   
    postPrioity=500
    echo "weeeeeeeeee ---> $postPrioity <--- 1"
done < /files.txt
echo "weeeeeeeeee ---> $postPrioity <--- 2"
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my guess! I think some of the other workarounds mentioned at BashFAQ (e.g. command grouping) are better bets, though - often your pipeline isn't meaningless.

Comment: Of course pipelines aren't meaningless in every case, but the construct “cat file | …” should in most cases be replaced by “… < file”. see e.g. the Bash Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide#BashGuide.2BAC8-Practices.2BAC8-DontEverDoThese.Don.27t_Ever_Do_These

Comment: Never knew this, thou I knew a little about subshell's.
But yeah ill keep this in mind now, and will have a read on those sites, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As a complement to Philipp's response, in case you MUST use a pipe (and as he pointed out, in your example you don't need cat), you can put all the logic in the same side of the pipe:

```
command | {
  while read line; do
    variable=value
  done
  # Here $variable exists
  echo $variable
}
# Here it doesn't
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use process substitution:

```
while read line
do    
    variable=value  
done < <(command)
```