# Bash append to variable using while read syntax

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have file which looks like following:

```
/usr/local/bin
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/home/user/.local/bin
/home/user/bin
/home/user/perl5/bin
```

now I want to concatenate the lines by colon using while read syntax, something like this:

```
cat file | while read data; do path="$path:$data"; done && echo $path
```

but above code is not working that I am expecting, the $path variable remains empty, what is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't read variable that was stored from within a while loop, when out of the while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529739/cant-read-variable-that-was-stored-from-within-a-while-loop-when-out-of-the-wh)

Comment: thanks, I learned something about pipes and PIDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this output doing the following:

```
$ tr -s '\n' ':' <file
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/perl5/bin
```

It replaces all new lines with a colon.

Regarding the error in your syntax, note that the proper syntax is:

```
while read data
do
   ... things ...
done < file
```

Comment: +1 for the loop syntax. +0 for the tr command - it indeed replaces  all newlines with a colon, including the last, which produces an unwanted trailing colon (that is missing from the above output).

Answer (score 1):

We don't need a loop or an external command.

```
path=$(<file) && path=${path//$'\n'/:} && echo "$path"
```